# How to alert pop up if no wifi or Internet 3G connected?

Tags: android, webview, wifi, toast

I am creating the application that using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And I am using WebView to launch URL. But when mobile didn't connected to WIFI and Internet 3G, in WebView appear exactly URL link.

I don't want user can see the URL link in WebView if no internet connection, how can i do it?

Best Regards,
Virak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the return of the following function (true for online, false for not) and modify the output depending on what you're after.

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

If what you want is to show a popup or a toast if there is no connectivity, then having that function in your activity will allow you to do the following, which will show the Toast.

```
if(!haveNetworkConnection()){
    Toast.makeText(this,"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    //Do whatever you need if there IS connectivity
}
```

I like using the function I'm giving you (have no idea where I copied it from, months ago) because it allows me to easily modify it if I need it to only return true if I have wifi or mobile internet, allowing me for instance to download a high definition video **only** if the wifi connection is available.

Answer (score 0):

sample code on checking internet connection;

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET?
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Internet Connection NOT Present");
            return false;
        }
    }
```